# Fastest way to populate a Hashset

Tags: c#, performance, hashset

I need to regularly step through a large collection of objects and maintain the unique values of a particular String property within.

I'm using a Hashset to hold the unique values, but was wondering if it's more efficient to check if a value exists in the Hashset, or just attempt to add all the values?

Answer (score 2):

Your test is a bad test for the reasons that [Jon Hanna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506940/fastest-way-to-populate-a-hashset#comment30656208_20506941) stated and did not give you accurate results. When you call `Add` internally HashSet calls `AddIfNotPresent` and the first thing `AddIfNotPresent` does is check if the object exists (code gotten from ILSpy)

```
public bool Add(T item)
{
    return this.AddIfNotPresent(item);
}

private bool AddIfNotPresent(T value)
{
    if (this.m_buckets == null)
    {
        this.Initialize(0);
    }
    int num = this.InternalGetHashCode(value);
    int num2 = num % this.m_buckets.Length;
    int num3 = 0;
    for (int i = this.m_buckets[num % this.m_buckets.Length] - 1; i >= 0; i = this.m_slots[i].next)
    {
        if (this.m_slots[i].hashCode == num && this.m_comparer.Equals(this.m_slots[i].value, value))
        {
            return false;
        }
        num3++;
    }
    //(Snip)
```

So by doing `Contains` then `Add` you do a check to see if the object exists ***twice***. If you have many items in the bucket it is checking this could add up to a significant performance loss.

Comment: Yes, my second attempt agrees with your explanation, with the inference that Add() takes about 107% of the time of a call to Contains().

Answer (score 1):

As my original answer was generally derided, I've had another go.

```cs
Int32 maxUniques = 1;
Int32 collectionSize = 100000000;
Random rand = new Random();

while (maxUniques <= collectionSize)
{
    List<Int32> bigCollection = new List<Int32>();
    bigCollection.Capacity = collectionSize;

    for (Int32 count = 0; count < collectionSize; count++)
        bigCollection.Add(rand.Next(maxUniques));

    HashSet<Int32> uniqueSources = new HashSet<Int32>();

    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();

    foreach (Int32 num in bigCollection)
    {
        if (!uniqueSources.Contains(num))
            uniqueSources.Add(num);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("With {0,10:N0} unique values in a set of {1,10:N0} values, the time taken for conditional add: {2,6:N0} ms", uniqueSources.Count, collectionSize, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds));

    uniqueSources = new HashSet<Int32>();
    watch.Restart();

    foreach (Int32 num in bigCollection)
    {
        uniqueSources.Add(num);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("With {0,10:N0} unique values in a set of {1,10:N0} values, the time taken for simple add:      {2,6:N0} ms", uniqueSources.Count, collectionSize, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
    Console.WriteLine();

    maxUniques *= 10;
}
```

Which gave the following output:

> With          1 unique values in a set of 100,000,000 values, the time taken for conditional add:  2,004 ms
> With          1 unique values in a set of 100,000,000 values, the time taken for simple add:       2,540 ms
>
> With         10 unique values in a set of 100,000,000 values, the time taken for conditional add:  2,066 ms
> With         10 unique values in a set of 100,000,000 values, the time taken for simple add:       2,391 ms
>
> With        100 unique values in a set of 100,000,000 values, the time taken for conditional add:  2,057 ms
> With        100 unique values in a set of 100,000,000 values, the time taken for simple add:       2,410 ms
>
> With      1,000 unique values in a set of 100,000,000 values, the time taken for conditional add:  2,011 ms
> With      1,000 unique values in a set of 100,000,000 values, the time taken for simple add:       2,459 ms
>
> With     10,000 unique values in a set of 100,000,000 values, the time taken for conditional add:  2,219 ms
> With     10,000 unique values in a set of 100,000,000 values, the time taken for simple add:       2,414 ms
>
> With    100,000 unique values in a set of 100,000,000 values, the time taken for conditional add:  3,024 ms
> With    100,000 unique values in a set of 100,000,000 values, the time taken for simple add:       3,124 ms
>
> With  1,000,000 unique values in a set of 100,000,000 values, the time taken for conditional add:  8,937 ms
> With  1,000,000 unique values in a set of 100,000,000 values, the time taken for simple add:       9,310 ms
>
> With  9,999,536 unique values in a set of 100,000,000 values, the time taken for conditional add: 11,798 ms
> With  9,999,536 unique values in a set of 100,000,000 values, the time taken for simple add:      11,660 ms
>
> With 63,199,938 unique values in a set of 100,000,000 values, the time taken for conditional add: 20,847 ms
> With 63,199,938 unique values in a set of 100,000,000 values, the time taken for simple add:      20,213 ms

Which is curious to me.

Up to 1% additions, it is faster to call the Contains() method rather than just keep hitting the Add().  For 10% and 63%, it was faster to just Add().

To put it another way:
100 million Contains() is faster than 99 million Add()
100 million Contains() is slower than 90 million Add()

I adjusted the code to try 1 million to 10 million unique values in 1 million increments and discovered the inflection point is somewhere around 7-10%, the results weren't conclusive.

So if you're expecting less than 7% of values to be added, it's faster to call Contains() first.  More than 7%, just call Add().

Comment: Do the ratios stay the same if you call `SimpleAdd` first?

Comment: I ran through it myself and I was surprised, I got the same results as you even if I did release mode without a debugger, same for switching the order of the tests. However I would not trust 7% as a hard and fast number, the quality and speed of the GetHashCode function that `T` in `HashSet<T>` uses will greatly affect the point at which it turns over. Also to rephrase that 7%, it is faster to call Contains when 93% of all items you attempt to instert already exist in the collection; I am having trouble thinking of many non contrived examples where I would have that high of a duplication rate.

Answer (score -1):

As I was typing the question it occurred that someone would ask why I did't just test it myself.  So I've tested it myself.

I created a collection with a 1.26 million records and 21 unique source strings and ran it through the following code:

```cs
HashSet<String> uniqueSources = new HashSet<String>();

Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();

foreach (LoggingMessage mess in bigCollection)
{
    uniqueSources.Add(mess.Source);
}

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Time taken for simple add: {0}ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds));

uniqueSources.Clear();
watch.Restart();

foreach (LoggingMessage mess in bigCollection)
{
    if (!uniqueSources.Contains(mess.Source))
        uniqueSources.Add(mess.Source);
}

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Time taken for conditional add: {0}ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
```

With the results that:

> Time taken for simple add: 147ms
>
> Time taken for conditional add: 125ms

So for my data at least, checking for existence doesn't slow things down, it is actually slightly faster.  The difference it pretty small either way, though.

Comment: That's not really a good test. 1. You haven't tried enough items, since 147ms is not enough to hide noise, the cost of jitting `HashSet<string>.Add` for the first time, and so on. 2. You're calling `Clear()` which will empty the set, but leave the internal table larger than on first creation, so it won't have to grow, which is one of the biggest costs to `.Add`.

Comment: You'd also want to run tests across a range of hit/miss ratios, as what works best at 1% new additions could be very difference to 100% new additions.